# How to leave ScrollViewer's focus with keyboard navigation in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm having issue with keyboard navigation and `ScrollViewer`. This is my setup:

```xml
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Add" />
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Clear" />
    <ItemsControl DockPanel.Dock="Top" Focusable="False" 
                  ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Item.Name}" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Selected}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer Focusable="False">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
    </ItemsControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Moving focus with Up and Down arrow keys works fine until focus enters my `ItemsControls`. Then I can only move focus inside it. For example if I reach ItemsControls' top item I would expect focus to jump back to my "Clear" button, but it doesn't, it's stuck inside ItemsControl. I tried various `KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation` options, but nothing works.

Removing ScrollViewer fixes the navigation, but that obviously isn't viable since I need to display more items that fit the screen.

Any ideas?

Comment: Itemscontrols are an exception to the usual keyboard navigation rather than the norm. Try tab.

Comment: I can't use Tabs since it doesn't make sense from the navigation point of view (and user's POV) because rest of the application is perfectly fine controllable with just arrow keys.